# como corregir error en sitanxis con nombre de columna en dataframe ¿?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data

Estoy ejecutando este codigo para eliminar unos registros de un dataframe, pero en la linea 16 (move_id/id) es el nombre de la columna y el / separa el nombre de la columna lo cual no es lo ideal. la respuesta de error es "move_id" no existe y es cierto xq la columna se llama "move_id/id"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import numpy as np
import dataiku
from dataiku import pandasutils as pdu
import pandas as pd

# Read recipe inputs
mpicon_acc_move_line = dataiku.Dataset("MPICON_acc-move-line_")
mpicon_acc_move_line_df = mpicon_acc_move_line.get_dataframe()


#CODE
exclude = ['mig2018.account_move__b00004629','mig2018.account_move__b00004636','mig2018.account_move__b00004670']
df = mpicon_acc_move_line_df[~np.in1d(mpicon_acc_move_line_df.move_id/id, exclude)] 


# Write recipe outputs
mpicon_acc_move_line_filtered = dataiku.Dataset("MPICON_acc-move-line_filtered")
mpicon_acc_move_line_filtered.write_with_schema(df)
```

Comment: Si no quieres renombrar la columna, accede a ella mediante `mpicon_acc_move_line_df["move_id/id"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al escribir:

```
mpicon_acc_move_line_df.move_id/id
```

Python interpreta que estás intentando dividir los valores de la columna `move_id` entre la variable `id`, ni la columna ni la variable han sido anteriormente declaradas.

Para acceder a la columna que quieres debes de en vez escribir:

```
mpicon_acc_move_line_df['move_id/id']
```